# Re-load div completely in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'm successfully adding AdSense into my Vue app. What I want is to re-load the ads on every 30 seconds. I tried to use setInterval to `this.adsense = false` and then back to `true`, but it says, that the `ins` already have ads in it.

```html
<div v-if="ads" class="ads"><ins v-if="adsense" class="adsbygoogle" style="display: inline-block; width: 320px; height: 50px;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXX" data-ad-slot="XXX"></ins></div>
```

```
mounted: async function () {
  let adsense = document.createElement('script')

  adsense.setAttribute('data-ad-client', 'ca-pub-XXX')
  adsense.setAttribute('async', '')
  adsense.setAttribute('src', 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js')

  document.head.appendChild(adsense)

  this.ads = true

  this.adsense = true

  ;

  (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is simply don't do it. It is against the terms of Adsense to auto-refresh ads (without the users causing it).

### Auto-refreshing ads

> Publishers are not permitted to refresh a page or an element of a page
>   without the user requesting a refresh. This includes placing ads on
>   pages or in placements that auto-redirect or auto-refresh.
>   Additionally, publishers may not display the ads for a preset time
>   (i.e., pre-roll) before users can view content such as videos, games,
>   or downloads.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en

Once you get banned from adsense it is near impossible to undo. I recommend you read carefully through all of their terms.

Comment: So, once the ad is served, the visitor is supposed to look at the same ad, for like, 3 hours, until he exit the website? Vue is a single-page-website...

Comment: You can refresh the ad but only when the user navigates between routes/views. Auto-refreshing is explicitly against google's terms.

Comment: Yes like @Terry suggests. When a user navigates to a different page of your `SPA`, you could trigger a refresh then. But doing it with `setInterval` is a bad idea.